# c# how the make datagridview.selectRow = bindingsource.position?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

how the make datagridview.selectRow = bindingsource.position??

```
sorry, i have no idea.
the datagridview' rowindex is not equals to the bindingsource' position. 
it is because i have set a relation of the bindingsource.
```

any one have suggestion?

Comment: David, you've asked a whole bunch of questions now about this same topic. I think you might be better served by finding a tutorial to help you understand how the datagridview works.

Comment: Now don't post a question for tutorial ;)

Answer (score 0):

try datagridview.selectedRow = datagridview.rows(bindingsource.position) with the correct syntax  I believe bindingsource.position returns an integer which you are trying to use as an index.